# Database connectivity in MySQL 5.5

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat

I have written these 2 files: 
register. html(which is for users for registering them) and register.jsp(for backend activity) 
when the user registers he gets redirected to the server page but after redirection the page is blank show nothing..
 Heres the code below for both the files:

`**Register(html)**

```
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form  action="http://localhost:9090/RegTrial/sel.jsp">
Rec: <input type="text" name="rec">
<br>
Comp: <input type="text" name="comp">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
<input type="reset" value="clear">                  
</form>  
</body>
```

**Register.jsp**

```
<html>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" language="java"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head> 
<body>
<%  
String rec_no=request.getParameter("rec");
String comp_no=request.getParameter("comp");
Connection con1;  
Statement stmt1=null;
ResultSet rs;
String recDb=null,compDb=null;
try
{
out.println("Rec:"+rec_no);
out.println("Comp:"+comp_no);
out.println("*****************************"); 

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/register";
String user="root";
String password="department";
con1=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
stmt1=con1.createStatement();
String query="select receipt_no,comp_no from receipt where receipt_no = '"+rec_no+"' and comp_no = '"+comp_no+"'; ";
rs=stmt1.executeQuery("query");
if(rs.next())
{
recDb=rs.getString(1);
compDb=rs.getString(2);
out.println("Rec:"+rec_no);
out.println("RecD:"+recDb);
out.println("Comp:"+comp_no);
out.println("CompD:"+compDb); 
if( rec_no.equalsIgnoreCase(recDb) && comp_no.equalsIgnoreCase(compDb))
{
out.println("already registered");
}
else
{
response.sendRedirect("www.google.com");
}
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
%>     
</body>
</html>
```

I have set the environmental variables:
CATALINA_HOME: D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.65

classpath: .;D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.65\lib\servlet-api.jar;D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.65\jar\mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar;

path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40

(Am using netbeans 7.3,mwsql 5.5,apache tomcat 7.0)

Comment: Hum [Little Bobby Table](http://bobby-tables.com/) would be proud.

Comment: Read the link and try calling your code with `rec_no` being `isn't it?`